# How can I have the return key function as any enabled button Swift/Cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa

In a Swift 2.1/Xcode 7/OSX project, I have several `buttons` in the UI, only one of which is enabled at a time. I have one editable `TextField`. I would like the return key on the Mac keyboard to also serve to "press" the currently enabled `button`. I can't figure out how to solve that through IB or code. Does anyone have any suggestions for an approach or a solution?

Comment: `NSApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(buttonName.action, to: buttonName.target, from: self)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set all the buttons' key equivalents to the return character '\r' (either in code or in the Xcode attributes inspector for the buttons). If you do that and only one is enabled, then typing return should be the equivalent of pressing that button.  Here's [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Articles/MakingaButtontheDefaultButton.html) on it.

Comment: That's exactly the perfect solution, @marckhadpe For those who may be perusing this, in IB the last choice under button in Xcode 7 is Key Equivalent, and in the blank space next to it, you just hit whatever key you like. Return will create a little curved arrow there, no actually typing in '\r' required.